# If you are given a binary knapsack problem with all items the same density (value/volume) how would you solve it?

Tags: algorithm

As the title is asking, not sure whether to use greedy method based on volume or if it is NP complete.

Comment: I flagged this question as not having anything to do with programming.

Comment: I think this question would be more suited for [or.se]. Also, you might want to read [ask].

Comment: If your max volume is `M`, you can solve it in `O(M)`.

Comment: Your edit to your question changed what’s being asked. If you want to ask something else, please feel free to do so, but do it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The binary knapsack problem where all items have the same density is essentially equivalent to the subset sum problem. In that problem, you’re given a set S of natural numbers and a target number k, and asked to determine whether it has a subset whose sum is exactly k. You can easily reduce subset sum to your problem by mapping each number in S to an item whose weight and value are the same. Since the subset sum problem is NP-complete, so is your problem.